# Load View controller in xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, xib

I was wondering if i could make some sort of a segue between these 2 views in a Xib file.

the main View is loaded into a scrollview in the storyboard.
[image].

(so if ik click Bewerken(edit) i would get pushed to the view controller on the right)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use a separate xib file instead of the storyboard?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "sort of a segue". A segue is a storyboard thing; you can't have one without the two controllers involved being in a storyboard. You can manually push or present that the controller though.

Comment: the content of the "main" view in this Xib is embedded in a UIscrollview in the storyboard file. @Eike

Comment: See my feedback as an answer below. I would suggest to switch to storyboarding with embedded segues.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing this to a Container View inside the storyboard instead of a separated Xib. You can add and position/size UIContainerView as a subview and add a"*Storyboard Embed Segue* to attach another ViewController. This is what it will look like in IB/Storyboard:
[image]

During runtime, the blue UIView (or the embedded UIViewController if you like) will be embedded in the hosting UIView as a subview:

[image]

If you change your implementation to this, you are in the beautiful segue world where you can just drag-and-drop segues :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do 2 things:

1 - Wrap the main view in a Navigation Controller so you can do the following:

```
@IBAction func loadEditController(sender:UIButton){

    let editController = RegisterController(nibName:"RegisterXIB", bundle:nil)

    navigationController?.pushViewController(editController, animated: true)

}
```

2 - Present the Edit Controller over the current context and animate it yourself

```
   @IBAction func loadEditController(sender:UIButton){

    let editController = RegisterController(nibName:"RegisterXIB", bundle:nil)
    editController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext

    presentViewController(editController, animated: false, completion: nil)

    //Move it offscreen and the animate it here


}
```